# Sql - how to build query with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a page that allow to search a product by `reference` or by `bar code` or by `alternative bar codes` in certain order list.

I need to get the reference and qtt columns from select.

To do that we have 3 tables:

- bi (list all products inside a specific order)
- sc (give us standard qtt by product reference)
- bc (gives us alternative bar codes, `this table has also qtt column`)

The problem is that it's possible that a product doesn't have alternative bar codes and in this case the `bc table returns null` and in this case I have to get the `qtt` in table `sc` but I don't know how to do that in same query.

My query is that:

```
select top 1 bi.ref, bc.qtt
from bi left join
     bc
     on bc.ref = bi.ref
where (bi.ref='00012' or bi.code='00012' or bc.code='00012') and
      bi.bostamp = ('orderID-0001')
```

The column `bi.bostamp` is the reference with order id.

So, I need to try integrate `sc` table in query to get `qtt` just when `bc` is null.

Thank you

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Case When to get the results you want.

```
Select Top 1 bi.ref, case when isnull(bc.qtt) then sc.qtt else bc.qtt end as qtt
FROM bi left join bc on bc.ref = bi.ref
left join sc on sc.ref = bi.ref
```

Does that work for you? This also assumes sc has a ref column like bc and bi.